# Facebook Mention Tagging new feature

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have a question about Facebook Mention Tagging explained in this link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/

Can i use that in my site that have an admin panel that enables a page admin to responce on fans questions which  require the admin to tag the asking fan, offcourse im using an app to connect my site with facebook but can it be done from my site outside the facebook comment box?

i tried using the prefix @[user Id:user Name] like [562156175:some one] but it does not appear in comment on facebook.

Note:

> im using facebook graph api and php sdk.

Answer (score 0):

No, i think it's mentioned in the documentation, but this only applies to Open Graph actions, which will need to be approved by Facebook before you can use tagging with them.

Comment: thank you lgy i guess i need to wait until they add the tagging and mentions to the graph api wich still in thier wichlist

Answer (score 0):

**You are doing mention tagging the right way, you're just missing one thing.** Before you can mention tag a user you need a comment from that user to the same post that you are trying to send a comment with a mention tag.

I have no idea why this is, maybe it's a bug or maybe it's the intended functionality, it's just... the way it is :)